# Is there a term for "likes" and "dislikes" on a social network?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms, programming, social-media

What is the term to use for "likes" and "dislikes" on social networks? Are they marks or grades or rates or anything else?

My purpose is that I'm programming a system where I have a `Post` domain object. It can be liked or disliked (as in every social network). Then how should the enumeration type representing these two values be named?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Given that ***upvotes*** is roughly synonymous with ***likes***, and ***downvotes*** is roughly synonymous with ***dislikes***, I might just call the general class ***votes***.

Comment: nice! short, simple and precise

Comment: I probably would go with "rank". (or maybe "rate", depending on system.) That said, "vote" or "votes" is perfectly fine.

Comment: @TheNate rank would be what you have after counting votes (up and down) and comparing other totals - rate would be a non-binary value, but you could still rank on the average of rate values

Answer (score 37):

Generally speaking **reactions** would apply here and is used on the messaging platform Slack.

Whether it's a like, a dislike, a thumbs up, a heart or a pizza emoji, the users are *reacting* to the post, so it makes sense to record these as **reactions**.

Comment: this is the correct answer. more commonly "reacts".

Answer (score 6):

You could consider using [**rating**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rating) which means:

> A classification or ranking of someone or something based on a
>   **comparative assessment** of their quality, standard, or performance

Rating is a broadly used word when evaluating movies and TV shows. I don't see any reason why it can't be used when ranking or evaluating a post domain object.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: `rating` is calculated aggregation value over all `votes` done by anyone, but not the set of possible options which consists of `like` and `dislike`.

Comment: @pkuderov You rate the post by upvoting or downvoting in the same way critics rate a movie by giving stars.

Comment: Ratings tend to be a scale, e.g. 0-5 stars. You could generate a rating based on up/down-votes, e.g. the percentage of upvotes. But the individual votes are not usually called ratings.

Answer (score 5):

The best term would depend on the type of feedback system being used, though a more general term can always be used in place of a specific one:

- *Likes only*: **like**, **preference**, **upvote**, **recommendation**, etc.
- *Likes and dislikes only* (not always subtracted from each other): **vote**, **mark**
- *Multidimensional feedback* (eg like, lol, sad, angry): **feedback**, **reaction** (what Facebook calls them), **opinion**, etc.

Comment: "mark" is quite a good suggestion

Answer (score 3):

In a more generic sense, the term ***reputation*** as used by this site, is in the ball park.

It also yields some potentially fitting synonyms.

Comment: I'd say reputation is a term for aggregation of likes/dislikes. E.g. field `X` = count(likes) - count(dislikes) for all votes on this post by users can be named as `reputation`, but it doesn't represent single vote.

Comment: I agree. I just wanted to log this one in the mix as food for thought.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with likes and dislikes in Social Media programmatically we generally referred to the term 'Sentiment'.

Comment: We do? I've never heard of that.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to refer to both likes and dislikes, and their equivalent on other sites that don't use those terms, you could refer to them as:

> *Positive and negative **interactions** on posts*.

*Actions* could also be used in place of *interactions* and may be preferable.

---

Since they could also apply to comments, you could label comments as:

> *Positive and negative **exchanges** on posts*.

to create a distinction between them.

Answer (score 2):

Civilians might get a laugh to know

```
Ikes
```

is sometimes used for this, on the inside of social media database and software engineering.

There's no really good word that perfectly characterizes like, not-like, dislike and not-dislike {noting that not-like may or may not be the same as dislike, depending on the milieu .. not-like'ing a like on a post is totally different from dislike-ing a post .. depending on various things like what history is tracked, etc etc.}

Anyways

```
Ikes
```

is the smart-ass answer ***IF***, that's if, in terms of my pithy and critical comment above ...

> @pkuderov a critical issue is this ..... do you want this term TO USE AS A CIVILIAN DESCRIBING THESE THINGS. Or, are you a software engineer looking for the best term to use literally as a Class name, Parse (HAHAHA) Class name or the like ? If the former, probably "vote", if the latter, perhaps "mark" since "vote" is a more general thing. But see my pithy answer.

... if you were asking about the latter.

If you're asking about the former, it would be pretty awesome if "Ike" caught on in general parlance.  So ...

> Check out this post, did you ike it yet? Which way?!

... sort of thing. My local sports radio channel often discusses social media posts, you can imagine them saying something like

> such-and-such got thousands of ikes, but half are likes and half are dislikes.

Comment: "I dislike Ike!"

Comment: yay, I didn't know that :) makes sense and fits but can be unfamiliar too for all non-native-English teams. But still.. very interesing option, thanks

Comment: just a curiosity for you!

Answer (score 2):

This is ***feedback*** on the original post.

"Feedback" is a generic English term that means to give back to the author of some content an idea of whether you thought that content was good or bad. Typically seen as solicited by a service or product vendor (as in "send us your feedback; let us know how we're doing!") or as a categorisation term within software to describe mechanisms that allow users to rank or rate dynamically-managed content.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are a way to express ***[preferences](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/preference)***:

> - the  selecting of someone or something over another or others.

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: "Preferences", when used in software environments such as websites, is generally synonymous with "settings". As such, "preferences" would generally be used as the name of a section in which the user can make selections pertaining to many aspects of the software.

Comment: +1 to @recognizer, I think `preferences` is too ambigous in almost any domain model

Answer (score 0):

I would use the term "flag" and "flag setting" which is the terminology employed by the Drupal content management system (CMS) as it is generic and can be applied to systems that express preferences, but also to systems that record reactions, votes, and any other type of interaction regardless of context.

Answer (score 0):

Acceptance. It's a trait inherent to the object, not the observer, and it reflects a reaction of either approval or disapproval.

Comment: "Acceptance" indicates approval, so this doesn't fit the extension to dislikes.

Comment: @ChrisH I'd say 'Acceptance' indicates whether something is accepted or not. But I agree it does suggest 'like' more than 'dislike'

Answer (score 0):

If we were to use popular social media platforms as a reference, then what facebook has introduced in its latest offering is a set of **reactions** that you can apply to posts.

Given that facebook was among the first to introduce the 'like' concept, I guess it would be a matter of time before the term comes into mainstream usage.